# Fill a variable with "array_to_string" in a plpgsql trigger function

Tags: postgresql, variables, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.5

I'm working with PostgreSQL 9.5.

I'm creating a trigger in PL/pgSQL, that adds a record to a table (`synthese_poly`) when an `INSERT` is performed on a second table (`operation_poly`), with other tables data.

The trigger works well, except for some variables, that are not filled (especially the ones I try to fill with an `array_to_string()` function).

This is the code:

```
-- Function: bdtravaux.totablesynth_fn()
-- DROP FUNCTION bdtravaux.totablesynth_fn();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bdtravaux.totablesynth_fn()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

 DECLARE 
    varoperateur varchar;
    varchantvol boolean;

BEGIN
IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
varsortie_id := NEW.sortie;
varopeid := NEW.operation_id;

--The following « SELECT » queries take data in third-party tables and fill variables, which will be used in the final insertion query.

SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT oper.operateurs),'; ')
INTO varoperateur
FROM bdtravaux.join_operateurs oper INNER JOIN bdtravaux.operation_poly o ON (oper.id_joinop=o.id_oper) 
WHERE o.operation_id = varopeid;

SELECT CASE WHEN o.ope_chvol = 0 THEN 'f' ELSE 't' END as opechvol INTO varchantvol 
FROM bdtravaux.operation_poly o WHERE o.operation_id = varopeid;

-- «INSERT» query
INSERT INTO bdtravaux.synthese_poly (soperateur, schantvol)  SELECT  varoperateur, varchantvol;

RAISE NOTICE  'varoperateur value : (%)', varoperateur;
RAISE NOTICE  'varchantvol value : (%)', varchantvol;

END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION bdtravaux.totablesynth_fn()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And this is the trigger :

```
-- Trigger: totablesynth on bdtravaux.operation_poly
-- DROP TRIGGER totablesynth ON bdtravaux.operation_poly;

CREATE TRIGGER totablesynth
  AFTER INSERT
  ON bdtravaux.operation_poly
  FOR EACH ROW
  WHEN ((new.chantfini = true))
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE bdtravaux.totablesynth_fn();
```

The `varchantvol` variable is correctly filled, but `varoperateur` stays desperately empty (NULL value) (and so on for the corresponding field in the `synthese_poly` table).

Note:
The `SELECT array_to_string(…) ...` query itself (launched with pgAdmin, without `INTO varoperateur` and replacing `varopeid` with a value) works well, and returns a string.

I tried to change `array_to_string()` function and variables' data types (using `::varchar` or `::text` …), nothing works.
Do you see what can happen?

Comment: A trigger function needs to be considered in combination with the actual ***trigger***, which is missing.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I've added the trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My educated guess: you have a trigger with `BEFORE INSERT ON bdtravaux.operation_poly`. And `operation_id` is its `serial` PK column.

In this case, the query with `WHERE o.operation_id = varopeid`
(where `varopeid` has been filled with `NEW.operation_id`) can never find any rows because the row is not in the table, yet.

`array_agg()` has no role in this.

Would work with a trigger `AFTER INSERT ON bdtravaux.operation_poly`. But if `id_oper` is from the same inserted row, you can just simplify to:

```
SELECT array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT oper.operateurs),'; ')
INTO   varoperateur
FROM   bdtravaux.join_operateurs oper
WHERE  oper.id_joinop = NEW.id_oper;
```

And keep the `BEFORE` trigger.

The whole function might be simpler, can probably done with a single query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately my trigger was an "After trigger" (I had initially not published it).
I'm going to simplify my code right now thanks to your advice, then I'll keep looking for my empty variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was actually a "time" problem, but in my Python program.
It filled the "operation_poly" table, then the trigger was launched and the other tables were filled. So, when the trigger was launched, other tables were still empty. Sorry for the noise. :-|

Answer (score 2):

## using `array_agg`

You can replace `array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT oper.operateurs),'; ')` with

```
string_agg(DISTINCT oper.operateurs,'; ')
```

And you can use **order by** to sort the text in the agregate

```
string_agg(DISTINCT oper.operateurs,'; ' ORDER BY oper.operateurs)
```

Comment: Ah yes, string_agg... I'd heard about il, but not yet used. Thank you.